# SQL Azure database trigger notification hub

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-notificationhub, database-trigger, azure-web-app-service

I have a SQL Azure database with one table on Azure and I want to trigger my notification hub when there is a change in the number of rows on my table so that I can send a push notification to my universal app.

I tried to trigger a WCF service so that I can then call my notification hub but with no luck. Also I don't think is the best way either anyway.

Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Did you get any working solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

i think that you can try using Logic Apps in this case linked to your services, so whenever there is a new row added in your database's table you can trigger your notification hub

take a look at this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-sql/

if you cant link your logic app directly to your notification hub try calling a web service