# Get the Azure Table values when it is updated through C#

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have to get the Table Values from Azure when it is updated in the SQL table. Is that possible with any utility?

Comment: There's a spiffy utility called SQL Management Studio that's pretty swell for extracting data from a SQL database.

Comment: Maybe identical question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490128/sql-azure-database-trigger-notification-hub

Comment: And you are looking something similar to trigger ?